# Configuring my domains for best search engine results

Tags: domains, multiple-domains

Couldn't think of a more decent question title, sorry.

Basically, I have 3 domain names:

```
mydomain.com
mydomain.net
mydomain.co.uk
```

The website is actually hosted at the .co.uk address, using nameserver addresses. What is the best way to deal with the two top-level domains. Do I add the same nameserver addresses to them, so all point at the same place? Or do I do a permanent redirect through my domains control panel? Or do I add a redirect in my windows IIS7 web.config file.

What I don't want, in Google listings, is all three domains listed. I just want .com or .net listed, but when visited, it goes to .co.uk site.

Any help or suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

For search engine optimization purposes, you will want to pick one of your domains to be canonical, and [use 301 (permanent) redirects](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066#301) on the others.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same situation but then for 2 situations. (.com/.nl)
we have chosen to make the .com leading and we have created redirects to always land the user on the ourdomain.com page. (this is a choise of course!)

this means we have one website which has binding for ourdomain.com (main website)
for all other options (we've chosen to also deal with use of www. or not) we created a separate website. This website redirects traffic for the following bindings:

- www.ourdomain.com
- ourdomain.nl
- www.ourdomain.nl

if any of these requests come in they are redirected to: ourdomain.com address.
This way in google we always get the same domain usage listed.

I'm sure there are more ways but this is how we do it. Have a good one.